# LaTex not compiling on VS Code due to BibTex

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, bibtex

I am having trouble compiling a book of editing using LaTex via VS Code and the following is the error message I get:

```
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
Latex failed to resolve 15 reference(s)
Latex failed to resolve 4 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
bibtex waysofmentalprayer: Could not open bibtex log file for 'waysofmentalprayer'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

It seems that the problem is bibtex. I was playing around and decided to rename the file extension from .bib to .tex and it worked. However, when I use Rstudio, it compiles perfectly with the file extension .bib. Why is this happening?

**Update**: The document compiles on Rstudio but the citation doesn't work. All that appears is `?` instead of the citation.

**Update 2**: It seems that on my local machine, it is not recognizing bibtex. I downloaded TeXworks but the bibtex option was in gray i.e. I couldn't use it. Does this mean I can't use bibtex?? How do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I have answered it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516512/144601). Basically, I used biblatex instead of natbib.